# ModX Gallery Watermarks

Tags: modx, watermark

I use the Modx Gallery Extra and tried to add watermarks onto my Images with phpThumbOn and phpThumbOf without success! Any idea how to add watermark to the Images?

I tried

```
[[+image_absolute:phpthumbon=`w=800&h=450&zc=1&fltr[]=wmi|assets/img/watermark.png|BL|40|3|3|0`]]
```

and also phpthumbof.

Answer (score 0):

PhpThumbOf (http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php):

```
<img src="[[*tvimg:phpthumbof=`w=300&h=300&fltr[]=wmi|aaa.png|BL|55`]]" />
```

`tvimg` - your img TV

`w=300&h=300` - width and height of your output image

`fltr[]` - filter list:

`wmi` - water mark image

`aaa.png` - watermark image source

`BL` - bottom left (position of watermark img)

`55` - opacity (55%)